# Comma separated issue in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have flat file coming in this format. if you look at the last name  and String is comma separated with in double quotes.

```
First_NAME, last_name, Age

Eddie, "Eddie,Murray", 25
```

When I read this in informatica, Murray is allocated in the age column and load gets failed as age is defined as number.

Is there way I can handle this? CSV file is correct as it is having double quotes by differentiating as it is single value for last name. I am not sure how to handle this in informatica. I have tried possible option and but couldn't figure out. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Text qualifier of the source should be double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

open infa session > go to mapping tab > then go to sources and select the source > then select file properties > And you will see advanced window like this screenshot 1. Once you click on advanced tab, it opens window 2. Make sure optional quotes is selected like the picture - double quotes. 
[image: Screenshot]